# Macro for 2003 sumproduct function

Tags: excel-2003

I have been trying to create a macro to replicate the following function in Excel 2003:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Casework2!A2:A19>="1/1/2012"+0)*(Casework2!A2:A19<="31/12/2012"+0),--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Ongoing",Casework2!H2:H19)))
```

but with no success.

How can I count the number of rows with data on the worksheet, then use that range to replace the `A2:A19` range, then compare it to the `H2:H19` range and finally put the result into a specific cell on the table worksheet?

Comment: You can find the last row using: Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A64000").End(xlup).row which you can store in a variable and then pass that variable to create the above function in a string.

Comment: Irfan, thank you for taking the time to answer. Unfortunatley, I'm very new to all this. I think i understand the code above, but could i ask you to further explain how I "store in a variable and then pass that variable to create the above function in a string" ? thanks again.

Comment: Dim str_Row --------------------------------------------------str_Row = Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A64000").End(xlup).Row------ Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value = "=SUMPRODUCT((Casework2!A2:A" & str_Row & ">=""1/1/2012""+0)*(Casework2!A2:A" & str_Row & "<=""31/12/2012""+0),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Ongoing"",Casework2!H2:H" & str_Row & ")))"

Comment: Irfan, thank you again, i can see how the str_Row variable fits into the function, but could you explain how i now get the results of this calculation to display on a worksheet, say in cell D:4?  thanks again,

Comment: Change -- Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value to Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).Range(D4).Value

Comment: Hi again Irfan, I have placed your code into my macro, but i get a "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error when using you suggestion of "Range(D4)". If it helps you, my data is on the sheet called Casework2 and i want the result to be on a sheet called Data, thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Put D4 in double quotes

Comment: tried your suggestion, but still not gwtting the result on my "Data" worksheet...

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer (@Irfan's code would be trying to write D4 to Sheets(1) ) please try:

```vb
Sub SUMP()
Dim str_Row As Long
str_Row = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Casework2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Casework2").Range("D4").Value = _
"=SUMPRODUCT(--(Casework2!A2:A" & str_Row & ">=""1/1/2012""+0)*(Casework2!A2:A" & str_Row & "<=""31/12/2012""+0),--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Ongoing"",Casework2!H2:H" & str_Row & ")))"
End Sub
```